# Pass Encrypted String as a jsp parameter from one jsp to other

Tags: java, jsp, encryption, urlencode

I'm facing a problem with sending encrypted string as a jsp parameter to other jsp. It has  spaces,/,+ alphanumeric characters

here is how my encrypted string looks like

```
var dataString="lREsIY9bcUFi9hETEJijk2yePcXAymOA9v+fW1MpTjJjZtuQJmAfyPzLJWjXM+9Qn6TC5dRBrU90KV/S9wmHw5Qpxo2DYmdjQtZlTwZWDoB1O+izeiBU90ZWJELSExFyHMSNVS5P/dnLw/+dp4O";
```

I get this error in the firbug's console:

> Error in processing! [object Object]

if I pass a normal String, everything works fine, I get redirected to the jsp  but not  for the above string.

Here is a code snippet and **passOnData** is the variable which I have passed as a parameter in the link:

```
 if(passOnData!=""&&passOnData!=null){
                     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",

                         dataType:"text",
                         contentType: "text/xml",
                         url:  "http://localhost:8000/secure/transaction.jsp?UserId=ABC&UserNo=110033&data="+encodeURIComponent(passOnData),
                         success: function(x) {

                         },
                         error: function( textStatus) {
                             console.log(' Error in processing! '+textStatus);
                         }
                     });

                    }
```

Is there any solution to my problem?Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Urlencoding is the magic you'll need. The + is converted to space (%20) otherwise and will mess up the data you receive.

You could replace your `+` with `%2b` or do a proper encoding with

```
 passOnData = URLEncoder.encode(passOnData);
```

before send.

There are web-safe base64 implementations that don't use those characters.

Comment: Thanks. i tried using URLEncoder.encode() as well as encodeURI and encodeURIComponent.
I get this error for all the three. in Firbug's console:

error permission denied to access property apply from jquery . i use jquery1.9.1,js

Comment: Can you update what you did in your question? And highlight the line in error?

Comment: Code looks fine that way. Or is passOnData no longer a string but an object now? You need to check line no on error maybe or log passOnData before the call?

Comment: you are right. but i use passOnData in jquery. and it takes the data type automatically right?
Error in processing! [object Object] .This is what i'm still getting.I tried comparing pre-encoded and post-encoded values. passOnData gets encoded. But when the ajax call is done and ready to redirect, I get this error.

Comment: Try this: var url =  "http://localhost:8000/secure/transaction.jsp?UserId=ABC&UserNo=110033&data="+encodeURIComponent(passOnData); before your ajax call and see it THAT works. Or isnthe error maybe after your now successful call in onSuccess?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the special characters. Use `Use URLEncoder.encode()` method